# Is there a way to get relative center of a Rect object in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

Now, suppose I always want to draw a circle at the center of a rect object, now, the problem is:

For example, if I do

`pygame.draw.circle(Surface, BLUE, Surface.rect.center, radius, width=3)`

This will and does fail because `Surface.rect.center` is actually the coordinates of the center of the Rect object relative to the (0,0) point -top left corner- of the display screen, not relative to the (0,0) point of the Rect object. However, the draw() function works relative to the Surface coordinate axis.

As far as here, those are my knowledge and I just think so, might be wrong in some aspects, if so, please let me know.

So, I can solve this simply by replacing `Surface.rect.center`, with:

`(Surface.rect.width // 2, Surface.rect.height // 2)`

However, I wonder, is there a way to get that center coordinate of the Rect object relative to its (0,0) point(origin) ?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [pygame docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) on the Rect class, there doesn't seem to be any specific to obtain what you're looking for, but it's easy enough to calculate the way you did.

Is there any reason you want to avoid using `(Surface.rect.width // 2, Surface.rect.height // 2)`? If not, I'd say it's the best option.